# How do I know if the user has provide rating?

Tags: app-store, storekit

So I am using `Storekit` for rating my app, but I do not want bother my app user if they already submit a rating! I found it is kind of not convenient to pop rating if they already done. I could make a variable to save that my app already asked for rating, no issue there, but I cannot get the result, if that task was successful. Is there a way for it, to stop asking for rating if the user already done it successfully? thanks

Comment: From documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: I have no issue to use case of Storekit or the best algorithm for that, my question is about knowing if user already done rating or not.